# Custom Glyph Group

Tags: adobe-illustrator, glyphs

Is it possible to create a custom group of glyphs within Illustrator?

There are a few select glyphs that I use repeatedly at work that come from a few different typefaces and it would significantly speed up my workflow if I didn't have to switch back and forth all of the time.

I have been able to save the graphic styles, color swatches, and brushes I use often as custom groups and have these be open by default, but haven't been able to figure out if this is possible with glyphs.

I'm sure I could make these glyphs into symbols and save those as a custom group, but I need to be able to keep the glyphs as text elements and not as graphics.

Could I create a "custom font" out of the glyphs and have it work that way?

Is there a 3rd party add-on for Illustrator that can create a custom glyph group?

Comment: https://glyphsapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @JGallardo's comment on my initial question, I looked into the Glyphs App to help solve my problem.

I used Adobe Illustrator CS6 and the Glyphs Mini app to select the glyphs I use repeatedly and create a custom font of them to help speed up my workflow.

There was lots of information, tutorials, and help available on the Glyphs website/forum to aide me in my journey to achieve this. It was fairly easy and straightforward, and I recommend it as a solution to anyone who wants to do something similar.